For a step down transformer, does the number of wraps in the secondary winding matter as long as the primary:secondary ratio is the same?
For instance, stepping down from 120 V to 5 V, the ratio would be 24:1. So does it matter if it is 24:1, 48:2, 72:3, etc.? If so, how many wraps should be on the secondary winding if I am to design a FWB rectifier circuit to convert 120 V AC to 5 V DC?

It's really more of a question of how many turns are required on the primary side to keep the magnetizing current down to a reasonable level -- i.e., high enough primary inductance with a given core. The number of secondary turns follows from that.


For instance, stepping down from 120 V to 5 V, the ratio would be 24:1. So does it matter if it is 24:1, 48:2, 72:3, etc.?

Yes, it matters.
Every transformer core has a required number of turns per applied volt (for a given frequency) to avoid saturation. Say the number of turns per volt to avoid saturation for a 60 Hz input is 1 turn per volt. If you want to step down from, say 120 V to 24 volts, you must have at least 120 turns in the primary, and 24 turns in the secondary. If you had only 60 turns in the primary, the core would saturate.
When the secondary of a transformer is open-circuit, the transformer is simply an inductor. The inductance of that inductor increases with the square of the number of turns.
$$L\propto N^2$$
The higher the inductance, the lower the current will flow through the primary at a given voltage and frequency. (Again, this is with the secondary open-circuited).
$$I \propto \frac{V}{L}$$
The magneto-motive force (MMF) in the core is proportional to the current times the number of turns.
$$\mathscr{F_m} \propto IN$$
Combining these facts, the MMF is proportional to voltage divided by the number of turns.
$$\mathscr{F}_m \propto \frac{V}{N}$$
Too much MMF (for a given core) causes core saturation, so one wants to limit the volts per turn. Or, put the other way around, one wants there to be sufficient turns per volt.
What about when the secondary has current through it? Transformer theory says that for an ideal transformer, the current through the secondary does not increase the MMF in the core, because the secondary current is matched by an opposing current in the primary in the appropriate ratio. So, we only need to consider the case where the secondary is open-circuit to determine whether there are enough turns per volt to prevent saturation.

Well if it didn't matter then we would just use one turn on the secondary side, because that's easier and cheaper.
So clearly there are other considerations. To understand them you need a more complete model for the transformer.
